# how to automatic update file `.less` in custom theme magento2?

Tags: magento2, less-css

In custom theme i have create file custom.less  after  **Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache** and **Fersesh cache** it  compiling .less files to CSS. but after i change file custom.less this file not update. i tried set Client-side LESS compilation it not luck. So anysuggestion? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to re-deploy by command. Even if you are running in production mode

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Or you can do it manually by clear asserts and static files in

> pub/static/frontend/[Vendor]/[YourTheme]/en_US/css

> var/cache

> var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/[Vendor]/[YourTheme]/en_US/css

Comment: Thanks @mrtuvn so if i change custom.less i repear this.  I want it automatic update when i change file less.

Comment: I think it still bug in m2. Tested in apache 2.4.7 linux no symlink. I already delete less in pub/static in developer mode but magento not re-generate it again. Only re-gen in command way. Same problem with javascript files

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below steps:-**

Just add new custom file here

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_custom.less
```

and import this file in source file given path below

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\web\css\source\_sources.less
```

import your file

(if there is not available _source.less file in your theme then go to `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source` folder and copy file in your custom theme)

```
@import '_custom.less';
```

1. clear cache
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and your `_custom.less` changes will compiling with your theme `.less` files.

Comment: I tried this and it's not working