# CSS files not update with _extend.less rules

Tags: magento2, less-css, less-import

I has installed magento 2 version 2.0.7-0, I trying to create my own theme but I can get archive that styles in `_extend.less` work correctly.

This is my path theme:

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themeName>
```

Inside the themeName I has created this folder structure:

```
.../<themeName>/web/css/source/
```

and put two files in source folder: _extend.less and _slider.less, _extend.less file import _slider.less as follow:

```
/* _extend.less file */

@import '_slider.less';
```

And in _slider.less file I include this rules:

```
/* _slider.less file */

#slider-home {
    .owl-carousel {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;     
    }
}
```

I have done magento in developer mode, I trying compile less files in browser instead server php less compiler, I deleted all files in static folder except `.htaccess` and regenerated with

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and nothing work, rules inside _slider.less not found in any css file generated in static folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clear generated files by deleting

> pub/static/frontend/[Vendor]/[YourTheme]/

For more information on this issue see this answer - [how to automatic update file `.less` in custom theme magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107103/how-to-automatic-update-file-less-in-custom-theme-magento2)