# proper way to use .less files in custom theme?

Tags: css, custom-theme, less-compilation

I've followed a number of guides to properly setting up .less files in a custom magento theme and nothing seems to be working.  I've read these threads on here:

[how to automatic update file `.less` in custom theme magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107103/how-to-automatic-update-file-less-in-custom-theme-magento2)

[Unable to import custom less file in custom theme's modules in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231875/unable-to-import-custom-less-file-in-custom-themes-modules-in-magento2)

[How can I add custom less file and in a particular theme compile less file in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142783/how-can-i-add-custom-less-file-and-in-a-particular-theme-compile-less-file-in-ma)

and poured over this page on the magento 2 docs:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html

I tried making  modifications in:
 {mythemedir}/web/css/source/_extend.less
 {mythemedir}/web/css/source/_extends.less
 {mythemedir}/web/css/source/_theme.less 
 {mythemedir}/web/css/source/_styles.less

I've made local copies of the styles-l.less and styles-m.less from the blank (which had imports for source/_sources.less and source/_theme.less)

At this point I'm just trying to drop a simple custom class in to see that it properly gets added to the site css, but nothing I tried generates anything anywhere in the static files:

```
> rm -fr pub/static/frontend/Magento/custom
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> grep -r customClass pub/static
>
```

I also then check by Ctrl-F5 reloading the test page with a block assigned that class and nothing.

So what the hell is necessary to get the built in .less to function properly in a custom class?

Answer (score 1):

You must delete css file from core theme in 
pub/static/frontend/
var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/

Comment: I did catch on to that one. I was clearing out the static but missing the pre_processed. But it still wasn't grabbing the content in the other files. Not sure what was going on there. I eventually just added an include right in the -l and -m files pointing to my own _custom.less in sources. It seems to work for my immediate need.

Comment: what is the 'recommended' or 'best practice' location for the custom css? extend.less? extends.less?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Your_name_module/Your name/web/css/source/_theme.less                      and you must type bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: ok, but without overriding what is already there. We are currently inheriting from Magento/blank but may inherit from another theme at some point if we can find one that does things already that we like.

Comment: To add a new source (CSS or JS) to all pages, the configuration is done through the default_head_blocks.xml file. It is also possible to add it to a single page only through the layout file for that layout handle

Comment: I ended up finding that I could add my custom stuff to the _extend.less (no 's') and it appears to work without a lot of extra hassle.